# What year was Hechler forcing created?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

Hechler forcing is described on page 278, Jech.

Does anyone know when Hechler forcing was first used in a publication?

Comment: Incidentally, Erin, Hechler sometimes shows up at our seminar, although it has been a while since I've seen him.

Comment: That's awesome, I hope I get to talk to him someday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The citation is given on page 283 of Jech (at least, in the 3rd Millenium edition); it is to Hechler's paper "On the existence of certain cofinal subsets of $^\omega\omega$," in the collection "Axiomatic Set Theory II" (see http://www.ams.org/books/pspum/013.2/9987/pspum9987.pdf), which is the only paper by Hechler in Jech's bibliography. It is somewhat difficult to read, but I think that we call "Hechler forcing" is a simplified version of the forcing introduced on page 159 of that paper; it seems reasonable to assume that this is its first instance.

(An historical note: Jech cites Hechler's paper as "[1974]," which is the date the collection "Axiomatic Set Theory II" was published; but that collection is the proceedings of a symposium held in *1967*.)

Comment: Thank you Noah.  I just now was about to post that I had found it in Jech.  And, the paper is very helpful.

Comment: @Erin: As a rule of thumb, it's usually a good idea to check Jech's book[s] and Kanamori's book[s] before asking. It's usually where the answer is going to come from anyway.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, when I was a graduate student, Adrian Mathias and I were once discussing some set-theoretic matter, and when I told told him that I thought it was in Jech's book, he told me that he tried never to look things up there, since to do so, he felt, meant that he had failed himself. And indeed, Adrian figured it out what we were talking about just then. (But of course citation and reference information are a different matter...)

Comment: @Joel: I never believed in that attitude. I agree it's important to be able to reprove things on your own. But I never felt the constant need to halt everything I want to work on, just in favor of "not failing myself". Finding new truths is more important, to me, than proving to myself that I am as good as the people before me. (But of course you're right, citations and historical references are something else completely, which are really what I meant in my comment...)

Comment: Oh, I think the attitude is a very good one! For my part, I'm glad to have picked it up from Adrian. The point is that one learns things more deeply when figuring it out on one's own, and surprisingly often, one finds a better way to do things. This is especially important when one is just starting on a new topic, which is not yet completed in the other accounts, since otherwise one can get trapped in someone else's unproductive perspective.

Comment: @Joel: I'm not disagreeing. In particular when working on something new, yes. But I think that the ability to connect results is as important as the ability to connect the proof techniques. Of course, at the end of the day, if you can't prove your results then you only did half the job; but I doubt anyone would say that being able to understand and apply connection between theorems and ideas is less important than coming up with proofs. That been said, I'm still at the point where I can't be sure to have either of these skills... Hopefully I'll turn out with both, but only time will tell. :-)

Comment: It's funny.  I was looking everywhere for this reference and then it hit me to look in Jech :)

Comment: In connection with "somewhat difficult to read", it may be worth reminding people that the 1967 symposium was, I believe, where both Shoenfield's unramified forcing and Scott and Solovay's Boolean-valued models were first presented. Before then, forcing was usually done in the style of Cohen's original work, using a ramified language of terms in a forcing extension of $L$, using strong rather than weak forcing (strong forcing doesn't respect classical logic), etc. No wonder it was difficult to read.  (Young people nowadays don't realize how good they have it.)